# Why is FileInputStream closing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a video file from local storgae by chunks and upload to a server. I have this code working in another java platform so i thought it would be quite simple.

When i try to open the File using

```
 File f = new File(filePath);
 fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
```

it opens and i can read whatever i need from the file, further down in my code though i call

```
    SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket socket = socketFactory.createSocket(url, 443);

    _in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    _out = (OutputStream)socket.getOutputStream();
```

The socket connects fine but when I then come to read the FileInputStream after this bit of code I get stream closed exception.

Any ideas? I don't see anything in the log to show anything is failing but i can't read from the fileinputstream once i have conencted to the server??

Let me know if you need to know anything else to help.

Comment: is this exactly your code? Are there any try/catch blocks involved?

Comment: please add the reading code too..

Answer (score 1):

This example worked for me:

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try {
      System.out.println("Locating socket factory for SSL...");
      SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

      System.out.println("Creating secure socket to " + host + ":" + port);
      SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

      System.out.println("Enabling all available cipher suites...");
      String[] suites = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
      socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);

      System.out.println("Registering a handshake listener...");
      socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyHandshakeListener());

      System.out.println("Starting handshaking...");
      socket.startHandshake();

      System.out.println("Just connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class MyHandshakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener {
  public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Handshake succesful!");
    System.out.println("Using cipher suite: " + e.getCipherSuite());
  }
}
```

As snicolas said, `socket.startHandshake()` could fix your prob.

Comment: thanks guys for being so quick, let me see where the info gets me and ill let you know asap.

Answer (score -1):

you didn't call socket.startHandshake();

Comment: startHandshake doesn't seem to available to Socket class, I am reading using..  byte[] bit = new byte[bufSize - firstTotal.length];
                int n = fileIn.read(bit);

Comment: -1. `startHandshake()` cannot possibly fix any problem to do with unexpected closing of a `FileInputStream`, and you never need to call it at all: it is called automatically when you do the first I/O on the `SSLSocket`.